# Glassfish DB Connection Validation not working if set to "meta-data"

Tags: jdbc, glassfish

if the glassfish server loses connectivity with the DB the connections all die. I want to detect it and recover the connection.

When I set it to use "table", this works but when i set it to "meta-data", this seems not working. Anybody know why or is this a known glassfish bug?

Answer (score 0):

Likely not bug in GlassFish, but JDBC driver that caches meta data. This is also addressed in [GlassFish documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2431/abehp.html):

> *table*: Performing the query on a specified table. If this option is
>   selected, Table Name must also be set. Choosing this option may be
>   necessary if the JDBC driver caches calls to setAutoCommit() and
>   getMetaData().